# Regarding Progress Bar

Tags: android

I  want  to  add  a  Button    In   The  Progress  Bar.

Scenario  is :-

```
           1) I want  To search   a contact through Application. 

           2) During the Search I will  show Progress Bar.  

           3)Can I add  cancel   button  in the Progresss Bar.
```

Thanks in Advance.
Raj.
Android Developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button to appear alongside the ProgressBar. The ProgressBar control does not itself have the ability to show buttons.

You could even create your own control EnhancedProgressBar that wrapped all controls in a LinearLayout or similar and included the ability to cancel.